# Internet Shortcut file that works on Windows, Mac, AND iOS?

Tags: ios, windows, macos, browser, cross-platform

My company is setting up a file center for commonly shared forms, such as HR benefits and the like. Some of the files we have in these folders are shortcuts to webpages.

We tried .url files, but they don't work on Mac, we tries Webloc files but they don't work on Windows. We've also tried HTML and that works on both. However, none of these will open in a browser on our iPhones.

Is there a type of internet shortcut file that would work on all three devices (preferably without having to install additional applications on the iPhones)?